# Property fallback when using reflection in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this:

```
public class Test{
   public string Name{get;set;}
}

var instance = new Test();


Type t = instance.GetType();
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = t.GetProperty("Id");
```

I want to have some fallback function in my class so in our case when there is NO property named "Id", it will invoke my fallback function and handle it.

Bottom line, when someone will invoke it, I can return whatever value i want.

Comment: So you "own" the `Test` class, and can do whatever you with to do with it, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, and I want whoever is doing reflection, to have control on the returned value (of the invocation). thanks

Comment: If there isn´t it will return null.So what would you return instead?

Comment: @JohnKoerner - I just dont know if there is a syntax / magic function to support that. I got nothing to try myself except googling, and that had no results.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are looking for. You want to return a custom PropertyInfo if someone calls GetProperty with a property name that doesn't exist? Please update your question with a more specific desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

how about setting your fallback function before, (I'm assuming you can do this before you start invoking on names that might not exist), and then testing for null in the case of the questionable property name.

Such as:

```
public class Test
{
    [DefaultValue]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


        var instance = new Test();

        Type t = instance.GetType();
        // set up your fallback fucntion
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fallbackInfo = t.GetProperty("Name");

        //if else on the property lookup
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = t.GetProperty("Id") ?? fallbackInfo;

        // your code here
        Console.WriteLine(propInfo.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetPropertyValueOrDefault<T>(this Type t, object instnace, string Name, T defaultValue)
    {
        var prop = from p in t.GetProperties() where p.Name.Equals(Name) select p;

        if (prop.Any())
        {
            return (T) prop.First().GetValue(instnace);
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var instance = new Test();

instance.Name = "Jane";
Type t = instance.GetType();
string Value = t.GetPropertyValueOrDefault(instance, "Name", "JOHN");
Console.WriteLine(Value);   // Returns Jane
Value = t.GetPropertyValueOrDefault(instance, "Id", "JOHN");
Console.WriteLine(Value);   // Returns JOHN
```